# iOS Search Bar with Search Display controller: loading last search

Tags: ios, uitableview, replace, uisearchbar

In my universal application I am searching for video files in my data structure. It is a master detail application and the search table view is positioned on top of the table of the master view controller.

Everything works fine when I simply search for a keyword. What I want to do is to keep the last searched keyword in memory and if the user taps on the search field again the results for this keyword should be pre loaded. So I tried filling the search field when

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

is called. This loads the result table, but I am not able to access it. This doesn't work until I clear the search field with the search button or via keyboard.

Is there I way to activate the search result table or to clear the search field programmatically (setText doesn't do the job)?

I hope I could make the issue understandable and I am looking forward to your help

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

this will send the control after each character hit in your texfield and then you can apply your logic. For any further help please mention some detail.